# bool returning 24

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm making a library in C++ and have a bool that is always false but when I print it from another project it is 24.

Lib code

```
void Window::update() {
    closeRequested = false;
}
```

Other Project

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    init();
    wnd = new Window();

    while (1 == 1) {
        wnd->update();
        std::cout << wnd->closeRequested << std::endl;
    }

    wnd->~Window();
    end();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the window class.

Comment: First and foremost, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: You should not be calling a destructor directly. Instead use `delete` (but in this case you don't even seem to need memory allocated with `new`).

Comment: What is the definition of `closeRequested`?

Comment: Their is an SDL window and it checks if the close button is pressed.

Comment: What's closeRequested declared as? Is it an int (or a handle) by any chance?

Comment: It is declared as a bool.

Comment: are you sure that 24 is output from this line? You should put some string before, like `std::cout << "close flag:" << wnd->closeRequested << std::endl;`

Comment: I did that but it is still 24.

Comment: @Lewis `24` smells like trolling about `42` answers :-P ...

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a boolean variable returns `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`, always. The fact that you're getting a different value means either memory corruption, or you're not getting a boolean.

My vote is on the second. If the definition of the object differs in the two different source files the memory layout of the object can change, and you'll get a part of the object that doesn't correspond to the value that was written.

A mismatch in the object layout can be caused in different ways. Some of the common ones:

- Different structure padding settings between two source files.
- Different typedefs or `#define` macros resulting in different types for the members.
- Conditional macros that evaluate differently in one source vs. another.

Comment: I actually think that 0 = False and non zero = True, not necessarily 1. int isTrue = 24, if isTrue will evaluate to true.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: @ventsyv that is true if you're evaluating any other kind of integer type, but not a `bool`.

Comment: @Lewis you'll just have to dig deeper to find the cause. A good first step is to use `sizeof` on the object in both places and see if it matches.

Comment: I suspect OP is using an int as flag and either printing it unassigned or assigning it to something > 1

Comment: @Lewis: First thing I'd try is a clean rebuild. Make sure everything is built with the same version of the headers.

Comment: @ventsyv the title of the question specifically says "bool". I don't try to assume the question is misleading unless I find evidence to the contrary, and as my answer states there are plenty of other possible causes.

Comment: @ventsyv you are mixing 2 things. When integral value is converted to `bool` then 0 == false and non zero == true. When `bool` is converted to int, false == 0, and true == 1.